# getting Exception on Shared Preferences Store

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am trying to save Shared Preferences using this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("BluefreeSharedPreferences",0); 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
prefEditor = sharedPref .edit();
prefEditor.putString("UserName", userName);
prefEditor.putString("Password", password);
prefEditor.commit();
```

On Samsung Galaxy 1900 with 2.2.1 its not saving shared Preferences but on Emulator with 2.2.1 and HTC Y one with 4.0.3 OS it working fine.
I read some post as here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359 anyone can guide me is it still issue?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you've initialized the editor right, here's a little code i've written a while ago, it makes a preference of a counter and increments it upon execution

```
SharedPreferences counter = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor count_editor = counter.edit();
int currentCount = counter.getInt(packageName +"", 0);
currentCount++;
count_editor.putInt("times clicked", currentCount);
count_editor.commit();
```

try this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: hi thanks for your answer.but my code working fine for HTC and Samsung with 4.0.2 OS.its facing problem only on samsung galaxy 1900

Comment: both our codes work on my galaxy s2, however when i had both my device connected and emulator running, logcat didn't print for my device until i shut the emulator down.

Comment: hi svarog thanks for guide and help. I am using samsung Galaxy S 1900 with 2.2.1 OS ..its not as S2 . .